# Main organization data access in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to design fabric architecture for my organization and not able to find answers to following issue.

There are multiple organizations which will communicate over multiple channels along with private data in each peer of organization. Main organization wants to access all ledger data along with private data. Is there any possible way to get access to all existing ledger as well as private data?

Can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

That main org should be part of every channel in network and as well part of all private data collection, I think that's way to fulfill your requirements

Comment: But if there are so many organizations then there will be limitations to be part of each channel.